# custom style for mobile submenu

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to change the look of my site's submenu on mobile devices;
my theme already has a special style on mobile, my problem is it doesn't seem to work by media query

So I made my mobile menu including a styling for a dropdown submenu which shows when tested on small screen sizes but when I check my site on my phone, the default submenu which blends in from the right as animation shows. I don't know what to put in my css to change that or if it's somewhere else that I need to put changes. The theme is Twenty Nineteen and my page is https://demokratietalk.at

In the original css I found this code, which describes what happens but as mentioned before I don't know how it only targets mobile devices:

```css
.main-navigation .main-menu .menu-item-has-children.off-canvas .sub-menu.expanded-true {
  display: table;
  margin-top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  padding-left: 0;
  /* Mobile position */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100000;
  /* Make sure appears above mobile admin bar */
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  animation: slide_in_right 0.3s forwards;
  /* Prevent menu from being blocked by admin bar */
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using media queries in your css? For a mobile device, you can use the below to wrap around all the custom css you want for your phone.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  css {
    Your customer CSS goes here
    }
}
```

Check out the link from w3 school for more help - https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

Comment: I've made it mobile first so no but it isn't a screen problem: When I make my browser window small width I see what I coded but on my phone I see the original sliding in submenu.

Comment: So the mobile submenu could be edited with an extra class associated with it